# I am trying input a matrix A, a vector v, and a column vector c to calculate w=Av. My code provides me with the wrong powers of A

Tags: matlab, vectorization, cumsum

This code is in MATLAB, I am trying input a matrix A, a vector v, and a column vector c to calculate w=Av. My code provides me with the wrong product matrix of A.

There is something that isnt correct when I am mutipilitying the kth column to the A matrix.

```
function [w1] = method1 (A,v,k)    

    B = eye(size(v)); % creates an Identity. (vector of just all 1's)

    % calculating powers of matricies by A(A^3) etc and outputting B

    % matrix multipilcation isnt right
    for i = 1: length(k)   
        B = B + K(i)*A;     % mutipily the k th column by the matrix.  
        A = A*A;  % matrix mutipilcation 
    end
  
    w1 = B*v; % adding the matrixes together and computing for W.
end
```

Comment: [formatting help](/help/formatting). You need backticks _before and after_ your code

Comment: You seem to want `w = A * v`, what is the loop for? What is `c`? Please [edit] your question to fully describe the problem you're trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in three methods as follows.

```
clear, clc
n = 2000;
% A is a matrix of size n x n
A = round(10*rand(n)-5);
% v is a vector of size n x 1
v = round(10*rand(n,1)-5);
K = [2 4 6 8];
% Loop over different values of K
disp('Method 1:')
for k = K
    tic;   w1 = method1(A,v,k); toc
end

disp('Method 2:')
for k = K
    tic;   w2 = method2(A,v,k); toc
end

disp('Method 3:')
for k = K
    tic;   w3 = method3(A,v,k); toc
end

function w1 = method1(A,v,k)
c = 1:k;
B = c(1) * eye(size(A));
Ak = eye(size(A));
for k = 2:length(c)
    Ak = A * Ak;
    B = B + c(k) * Ak;
end
w1 = B*v;
end

function w2 = method2(A,v,k)
c = 1:k;
w2 = zeros(size(v));
Av = c(1) * eye(size(A))*v;
for k = 2:length(c)
    Av = A * Av;
    w2 = w2 + c(k)*Av;
end
end

function w3 = method3(A,v,k)
c = 1:k;
w3 = c(end)*v;
for k = length(c):-1:2
    w3 = A * w3 + c(k-1)*v;
end
end
```

The relative times are as follows:

```
Method 1:
Elapsed time is 0.147640 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.421866 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.682126 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.861816 seconds.
Method 2:
Elapsed time is 0.013014 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.016521 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.019014 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.022413 seconds.
Method 3:
Elapsed time is 0.001908 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.006269 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.008623 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.012608 seconds.
```

So, in conclusion, Horner method is the fastest and matrix-matrix multiplication is the slowest. Matrix-vector multiplication is in-between.